# Get File Uri from Document Id in Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-file, storage-access-framework

I am using directory selection as described in this [Google Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DirectorySelection). It does provide file name and mime type of the children of the selected directory. I can get Document ID of the file too, if I use `COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID` on the Cursor Query. 
I am interested in the file URI of the children instead. When I use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` instead of `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, I get the child uri easily which is just obtained from adding a `%2Fchildfile.extention` (%2F is just a forward slash). So I tried to get child file uri using the following code -

```
uri = Uri.parse(docUri.toString()+"%2F"+fileName);
```

I got the file name, however when I run exists() method on it (By converting it into DocumentFile), it returns false. That means, either I don't have the permission of the file or it's not the correct way to get children uri.

Am I missing something here or is there any other way I can select a folder and get file uri of all of it's children easily.

PS: I am currently checking it in Marshamallow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the doc and trying out certain examples, I got the following way to get a single file Uri from a selected docUri/treeUri

```
uri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(docUri,docId);
```

And then you can convert it anytime into a DocumentFile using following code -

```
DocumentFile file = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
   if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
       file = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri);
   } else {
       file = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri);
   }
}
```

`fromTreeUri()` method is required for the selected Tree Directory, so that it can return true on `file.exists()` method call.
You need to remember that if the children contain any directory, then you can't call `childDirectory.listFiles()` on it. It'll give `UnsupportedOperationException`, because you don't have permission to access the child directory's file. Read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#listFiles()).